# JQuery Validation Regex for Contain

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, passwords, jquery-validate

I have a username and password input field and I'm using the jquery validation plugin to validate my form. I know how to create custom rules and all but I'm just wondering how to write the regexp for it.

I want the password to be:
1) minimum 8 characters (this is taken care of by minlength in rules)
2) Contain a symbol (!@#$%^&*?~`'")
3) Contain a number (0-9)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("password", function(value, element) { 
        return this.optional(element) || /.../i.test(value);
    }, jQuery.format("Enter correct password"));
```

I just don't know how to write the regex to search the input and see if it contains at least 1 symbol and 1 number. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go

```
^(?=.*?[@#$%^&*?~`])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$
```

It tells, starting from the beginning of the string, that any string with length >=8 is ok

```
.{8,}
```

You need also to tell that from the beginning of the string you need a symbol in any position

```
^(?=.*?[@#$%^&*?~`])
```

And a digit in any position

```
(?=.*?[0-9])
```

using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[A working example](http://rubular.com/r/97mJwHektM)